# left string in a batch file

Tags: string, batch-file

I am writing a .bat file in which I'm trying to compare the last modified date of a file with the system date (date-only, not the time). To get the last modified date of the file, I use the following:

```
for %%? in ("anyFile.png") do set dat=%%~t?
```

This gives me the last modified date and time of the file (dat=31.08.2016 08:59). Now I try to cut the string to get only the ten characters in the beginning (31.08.2016):

```
set dat=%dat:~0,10%
```

If I type the code directly into the console it works like a charm, but in my batch file the console output only gives me the following:

```
dat=~0,10
```

I don't have a clue what I'm missing, and in the internet I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem neither.

Comment: This results from an empty variable `dat`; since you are specifying the file name only, I assume you are looking in the wrong directory (note that the working directory and the parent directory of the batch file are two different things!)...

Comment: But after the first command, if I enter "set dat" and "pause" right after them in the batch file, the console returns "dat=31.08.2016 08:59". Thus, the variable dat is not empty. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Would you mind showing a bigger part of your programm? Or are the two lines in your question the whole code?

Comment: Is the command line `set dat=%dat:~0,10%` placed within a parenthesised block of code? if so, you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @aschipfl for the hint, the problem with the dat variable could be solved with delayed expansion:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
if exist "anyFile.png" (

  for %%? in ("anyFile.png") do set dat=%%~t?
  set dat=!dat:~0,10!
)
```

@geisterfurz007: no, this was not the whole code. But as the problem is solved now, I think there is no need for it anymore. :)

Comment: I already thought about that problem, so I asked ;)
But well if it works now, all is fine.

Comment: You now have learned a valuable lesson with batch files. Often times other parts of your code affect the code you think is wrong.  If you would have just showed all your code in your original question the problem would have been seen instantly.

Comment: You technically do not even need the `IF EXIST`.  If the file does not exist nothing will be assigned to your dat variable. The dat variable would become undefined.